# Twilio get all purchased numbers on account

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I need to use the Twilio API in PHP to get all purchased numbers on my account so that they can be used in a `<select>` option in a HTML form.

Example:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Can someone show a basic example of how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The Twilio API documentation is pretty thorough and provides examples of how to make most of their calls. They also provide an SDK library to make it even easier. I believe the call you're looking for is `/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/IncomingPhoneNumbers` ([Twilio Documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers#list)). There is an example of calling it at that page:

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "ACdc5f132a3c49700934481addd5ce1659"; 
$token = "{{ auth_token }}"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

// Loop over the list of numbers and echo a property for each one
foreach ($client->account->incoming_phone_numbers as $number) {
    echo $number->phone_number;
}
```

You will need to get the "twilio-php" library, which can also be found on their site, or [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install).

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can get the list of numbers on your account by calling the [Incoming Phone Numbers list resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers#list-get). This is done in PHP, using the [Twilio PHP helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install), like this:

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "{{ account_sid }}"; 
$token = "{{ auth_token }}"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

// Loop over the list of numbers and echo a property for each one
foreach ($client->account->incoming_phone_numbers as $number) {
    echo $number->phone_number;
}
```

I'll leave it to you to turn that into the HTML output you need.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with:

```
$twilio=new Client(TWILIO_ACC_ID,TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);

//get all the phone numbers on account (assuming there won't be more than 1000)
$incoming_phone_numbers=$twilio->incomingPhoneNumbers->read([],1000);

//loop through all numbers
foreach ($incoming_phone_numbers as $number) {
    print("<p>sid: ".$number->sid." phone number: ".$number->phoneNumber."</p>");
}
```

Pretty different than what the other two have posted!  I tried those and they didn't come close to working.  Maybe I have a different version of the API or php library.

Also Twilio's documentation says to use `$number->phone_number` but that's clearly wrong.  It definitely comes back as `$number->phoneNumber`